# "Ne pas envoyer dire" in this sentence?

Tags: sens, expressions

I encountered this while reading *Astérix*. The sentence is:

> La première victoire revient incontestablement à Cloridric; celui-ci, ayant surpris Téléféric par un mouvement tournant, bing ! ne le lui envoie pas dire et lui inflige une cuisante défaite."

Given my understanding of *envoyer dire* as *to send a message*, I translate this by:

> The first victory was decisively taken by Cloridric; he, having surprised Téléféric with a turning movement-- bam! -- does not send him a message and inflicts a burning defeat.

That obviously makes no sense, therefore I am wrong.

Also, btw, are Cloridric and Téléféric jeux-de-mots ? Many of the Gothic names are, but I don't see it for those two.

Comment: Almost all the names in Astérix are wordplays: Astérix and Obélix first (from asterisk and obelisk), Cétautomatix ("c'est automatique"), Abraracourcix ("à bras raccourcis"), Assurancetourix ("assurance tous risques"), Babaorum ("Baba au rhum"), and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLFi offers at [*envoyer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envoyer) (and it's the only reference to *envoyer dire* I could find in TLFi):

> *Loc. fam. Il ne le lui a pas envoyé dire = Il le lui a dit sans intermédiaire et sans détours.*

I had to look it up, I would have stumbled here too. I could not have told directly what it meant. In this context though, it probably means that Cloridric was "direct" (by punching Téléféric).

*Cloridric* is a play on words, with *(acide) chlorhydrique*.

*Téléféric* is for *téléphérique* which is the French word for *aerial tramway*.

Comment: Ahhhh that does make perfect sense. By the way are you not a native speaker?

Comment: I am a native speaker (... of French). But this expression is IMHO not common in French today.

Comment: You can find another acide chlorhydrique play on words in the album "Astérix légionnaire" with a spy named [Acidcloridrix](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidcloridrix)

Comment: Frank, I feel like I must have heard this expression a few times a month throughout my life. Not super common, but not overly exotic either.

Comment: A few times a month? In France?

Comment: Canada is my country, French is my language. :) And I don't happen to have a crazy busy social life, though it's not dead either. A few times a month is in the league of _‘Jamais deux sans trois’_, more or less...

Comment: @Feelew - ok - then this expression is probably more frequent in Canadian French than in French spoken in France.

Comment: I'll have to accept your conclusion, for I have no real experience of France, only through a few expats that end up taking a bit of the local colour anyways.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic construction "ne pas envoyer dire" means "to be direct with someone", because "envoyer dire" connotes that you're sending an intermediary to go tell something to the person you want to say something to.

This kind of figure of speech is called in French a *litote*, and consists of producing emphasis by the use of a double negation, or negating the opposite of what we mean to emphasize.

Other, maybe slightly more common examples of idioms based on the *litote* pattern include:

- Ne pas y aller avec le dos de la cuiller (= really going at it)
- Ne pas y aller de main morte (= same)
- Ne pas tourner autour du pot (= not beating around the bush)

Comment: Let's not forget the wonderful (yet totally unrecommendable) [perronisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perronisme): _Ne pas y aller avec le dos de la main morte._